# Yii2 ActionColumn Duplicating Icons

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I am using the Yii2 Grid ActionColumn. I have a field in my Database called `log_type` with the values of either `Risk Assessment` or `Documentation` What I am trying to do is only show certain buttons when the `log_type` is `Risk Assessment` It works great for my `PDF` icon. But for my `Yes` and `No` Icons. It duplicates them only when set to show for `Risk Assessment` If I set it to show for `Documentation` It will only show 1 Checkmark instead of 2. See the code and screenshots:

```php
  <?php
    $gridColumns = [
        [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'header'=>'Action',
        'hAlign'=> GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'template'=>'{update}{view}{yes}{no}{pdf}',
        'buttons'=>[
            'pdf'=>function($url, $model){
                if($model->log_type == "Risk Assessment"){
                    return Html::a('<i class = "fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                    'pdf?id='.$model->id,[
                        'data-pjax'=>'0',
                        'target'=>'blank',
                    ]);
                }
            },
            'yes'=>function($url,$model){
                 return Html::a('<i class = "fa fa-check"</li>');
            }
        ],
        'visibleButtons'=>[
           'yes'=>function($model,$key,$index){
               if($model->log_type === 'Risk Assessment'){
                   return false; // Right here. If I change this to True I get the duplicate icons as shown in the screenshot. 
               }else{
                   return true;
               }
            }
        ],
        'urlCreator'=>function($action, $model, $key, $index){
            if($action === 'view' && $model->log_type === 'Risk Assessment'){
                $url = 'view-risk?id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }else if ($action === 'view' && $model->log_type === 'Documentation'){
                $url = 'view?id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }
            if($action === 'update' && $model->log_type === 'Risk Assessment'){
                $url = 'update-risk?id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }else if($action === 'update' && $model->log_type === 'Documentation'){
                $url = 'update?id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'id',
        'header' => 'ID',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>false,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'description',
        'header' => 'Description',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'log_type',
        'header' => 'Log Type',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'development_type',
        'header' => 'Development Type',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'platform_type',
        'header' => 'Platform Type',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'security_risk',
        'header' => 'Secuirty Risk',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'comments',
        'header' => 'Comments',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'risk_accepted',
        'header' => 'Risk Accepted',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'approved',
        'header' => 'Approved',
        'hAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_CENTER,
        'vAlign' => GridView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'filter'=>true,
    ],
]
    ?>
```

**Duplicate Icons**

[image: Duplicate Icons]

**Non-Duplicate Icons**

[image: Non-Duplicate Icons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried replicating your problem and I couldn't, but I think that it is related to this malformed tag:

```html
'<i class = "fa fa-check"</li>'
```

You open an `<i>` tag, but close with `<li>`. When I used your code, I didn't get any icons to display, even after updating the line where your comment about the duplicate icons is.

There also maybe a problem with the fact that you are both displaying conditionally the buttons on `buttons` and, at the same time, using the `visibleButtons` attribute. I think that it would be better to use one **or** the other, i.e. use `vibilbeButtons` for the inbuilt `view`, `update`, `delete` buttons, and, when possible, add your own conditional logic on the `buttons` attribute. The examples on the Yii2 guide all do it that way.

You can update the manually generated tags to use the [Kartik icon class](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-icons) to generate icons, and move all your logic inside `buttons`, having it all in the same place will make it easier to maintain, and it will work as expected:

```php
'template' => '{update}{view}{yes}{no}{pdf}',
'buttons' => [
    'pdf' => function($url, $model) {
        return $model->log_type == "Risk Assessment" 
            ? Html::a(Icon::show('file-pdf'),
                ['pdf/view', 'id' => $model->id] , [
                'data-pjax'=>'0',
                'target'=>'blank',
            ]) : '';
    },
    'yes' => function($url,$model) {
             return $model->log_type === 'Risk Assessment' 
                 ? Html::a(Icon::show('check'), ['controller/action', 'id' => $model->id]) : '';
    },
    ...
    ],
    'visibleButtons'=>[],
...
```

Comment: That is what it was. Thank you!